# Reading a .txt, Display it in Form, Edit in Form, and Save

Tags: c#, file, line, edit

I'm relatively new to programming and I've set up a "fairly" simple task for me to work on. What I am trying to accomplish is clicking on a "Settings" button on Form1 that will open and post the results of "config.txt" to labels on Form2.

Config.txt looks like this:

```
[VERSION] 7544
[WIDTH] 480
[HEIGHT] 768
[SCALE] 1
[UI] 8
[SERVER] 2
[DEMO] 1
[BRIGHT] 50
[CURSOR] 1
```

I have been able to create the .txt file if it does not exist with default values using

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("config.txt"))
{
    sw.Write("[DATA1] 7544");
    sw.Write("[DATA2] 8");
    sw.Write("[DATA3] 2");
}
```

I'm having issues reading the lines of code separately and displaying them to separate labels.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"config.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    string labelTest = string.Format(line);

    labelVersRead.Text = "Version: " + line;
    counter++;
}    
file.Close();
```

I believe the issue I'm having is saying `var line3 = line[3]`. I can only get it to output the complete .txt into a single string.

Comment: Does "having issues" mean you have an attempt to show? If so, post it. The code you use to write the file seems irrelevant.

Comment: You can [edit] your post; that's usually better than posting code in comments.

Comment: What's Data1 in the line "[DATA1] 7544" ? Does it have a mapping label?

Comment: var line3 = line[3] is not in the current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you could have a list.

```
var list = new List<Config>();
public class Config{
   string LabelText
   string LabelValue
}

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Split the line based on the pattern and build the list object for Labeltext and LabelValue.

    //You will have to come up with the logic to split the line into string based on the pattern. Where text in the [] is LabelTesxt and anything followed after ] is  LabelValue

    list.Add(new Config{LavelText = "VERSION" ,LabelValue="7544"});

    counter++;
}

//Once done, you could bind the data to the label
var item = list.Find(item => item.LabelText == "VERSION");
lblVersionLabel.Text = item.LabelValue
```

Comment: How does this work exactly?
Currently labelVersRead (label) outputs all of the config.txt.

Here you have defined LabelText and LabelValue. I'm not sure I understand how this works.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I'm not sure this will do what I am looking for. I will look further into my issue and perhaps I can explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you always overriding the `Text` for the label.

Use `+` to append the text.

```
labelVersRead.Text += "Version: " + line;
```

Or with new line at the end

```
labelVersRead.Text += "Version: " + line + "\r\n";
```

Is it this solve the issue you encounter ?

Comment: This actually provides the same visual results, as it outputs the entire config.txt into a single one-line string.